# How to obtain Image URL when i retrieve an entity in Symfony + VichUploaderBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

Thank to the VichUploaderBundle which make me easier to handle image upload in Symfony 4 framework.

When i obtain data from entity, it return me with entity data and image name. But i don't want to have image name only, because every time i need to write path for that image to display correctly.

**Note: For vich uploader config and entity mapping, it is exactly same on github docs so i won't paste it here cause i think it is unnecessary.**

---

Code Sample

Home Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

//.....

/**
 * @Route("/home")
 */
class AdminHomeController extends AbstractController
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/banner", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getHomeBannerList(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(HomeBanner::class);
        $home = $repo->findAll();

        $data = $serializer->serialize($home, 'json');
        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'], true);
    }

     /**
     * @Route("/banner", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function addHomeBanner(Request $request)
    {
      $file = $request->files->get('image');
      $home = new HomeBanner();
      $home->setImageFile($file);
      $home->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
      $this->em->persist($home);
      $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

When visit  /home/banner , it will give me:

```
[
  {
    "image" : "home01.jpg",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-14 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "image" : "home02.jpg",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-14 00:00:00"
  },
]
```

How can i make it to return with the image path and not image name only?

Comment: Could you please show the code for saving/finding the entity?

Comment: @dbrumann There you go~ just a simple controller code.

Comment: You can use the config option inject_on_load: true, in that case the path is injected automaticly everytime you query the images from the databse. But be aware in case you change the datetime in the setFile method, as it's described in the docs, will print you the current date instead of the updated one.